# Can not insert data to Google Spreadsheet because Postman returns error 404-requested resource can not be found

Tags: android, google-apps-script, http-post, http-status-code-404, google-sheets-api

I made a simple Android App for inserting data into Google Spreadsheet. Everything works but now when I tried to make another spreadsheet to insert data, application failed.
Of course, I used a different request URL from google script and I published it as a web App and a different sheet id. That means I did everything the same as the first time but my new App doesn't work.

I used Postman tools to verify doGet and doPost activities and in the first Application Postman returned 200 which means everything works, but when I tried the same for second Application or second spreadsheet Postman returned error 404-requested resource can not be found.

I tried to login to another google account but it has the same problem.
**Maybe, there are some limitations per user??**

Here is the code for Kod.gs/google script:

```
  function doGet(e){
     return handleResponse(e);
  }

  function doPost(e){
     return handleResponse(e);
  }

  function handleResponse(request) {
     var output  = ContentService.createTextOutput();

     var name = request.parameter.name;
     var country = request.parameter.country;
     var id = request.parameter.id;

     var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
     var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("List1");

     var rowData = sheet.appendRow([name,country]);
  }
```

In both Spreadsheets, I used the same columns: **name** and **country**, and of course the same values I passed in Postman's parameters.
Spreadsheets are with a different name.

Comment: It seems to me GAS can't open de spreadsheet by id.  May be id is wrong, may be it is inaccessible - not shared.  Start sharing it for everyone can edit, in order to verify if it works.

Comment: I tried but still not working.Id is ok and I also started sharing so everyone can edit and still nothing.